# How do I expand the plot margins so that chorddiagram doesn't cut of the labels?

Tags: plot, margins

```
chordDiagram(as.data.frame(DF2), annotationTrack = "grid", preAllocateTracks = 1)
par(cex = 0.5, mar = c(0,0,0,0)+5)
circos.trackPlotRegion(track.index = 1, panel.fun = function(x, y) {
xlim = get.cell.meta.data("xlim")
ylim = get.cell.meta.data("ylim")
sector.name = get.cell.meta.data("sector.index")
circos.text(mean(xlim), ylim[1] + .1, sector.name, facing = "clockwise", niceFacing = TRUE, adj = 
c(0, 
0.5))
circos.axis(h = "top", labels.cex = 0.5, major.tick.percentage = 0.2, sector.index = sector.name, 
track.index = 2)
}, bg.border = NA)
```

I am looking for advice how to change my coding to ensure that the labels do not get cut off by the margins?

Answer (score 0):

https://flic.kr/p/2iQ8WCb

Here is the link for the photo example.